Spectral Theorem for normal maps in complex scalar spaces
I'm revisiting my first year lecture notes, but embarrassingly cannot follow a crucial step in a proof and would like to have some opinions on this:
Let $V$ be a finite dimensional complex-scalar space, $\varphi: V \rightarrow V$ a normal map. Then $\varphi $ is diagonalizable and it has ONB consisting of its eigenvectors.
Proof sketch:

Let $\lambda_{1}, \ldots, \lambda_{r}$ be the Eigenvalues of  $\varphi$

For every Eigenspace $E_{\lambda_{i}} ( \varphi)$ we have ONB $B_{i}$ . Consider $B :=B_{1} \cup\cdots\cup B_{r}$, which is a ONB of a (potentially) subspace $L \subseteq V$

We want to show $L=V$:


Let $B=\{v_{1}, \ldots, v_{n} \}$ . Then $L^{\perp}$ is kernel of
$$
\psi\colon V \to\mathbb{C}^{n}, \ v \mapsto\left( \langle v_{1}, v \rangle, \ldots, \langle v_{n}, v \rangle\right), 
$$
$$
\operatorname{dim} ( V )=\operatorname{dim} ( L^{\perp} )+\operatorname{dim} \left( \operatorname{Im} ( \psi) \right) \leq\operatorname{dim} ( L^{\perp} )+\operatorname{dim} ( L ). 
$$
Now the argument that I don't understand:
Assume $L^{\perp} \neq\{0 \}$ , then there is an eigenvector in $L^{\perp}$, because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed and
$\varphi(L^{\perp}) \subset L^{\perp}$.
(This is a contradiction so $L^{\perp}=\{0 \}$ and by the dimensionality argument $L=V$. $\square$ )
I reckon the algebraic closure has to do with the characteristic polynomial, but I cannot for the life of me understand how I can put these together. I can see $\varphi(L^{\perp}) \subset L^{\perp}$, but I'm perplexed as in why something in $\operatorname{ker}(\psi) = L^{\perp}$ has to be a Eigenvector.
On a side note, the wikipedia article (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Hermitian_maps_and_Hermitian_matrices) has a proof for the special case of hermitian maps and builds the ONB from scratch, without showing that the finite induction ends with $L=V$? Why is it (not) necessary? Why did we do this in the lecture notes?

oh sorry, my bad. you meant normal maps...

The main idea is that both $L$ and $L^\perp$ are fixed subspaces (fixed by $\phi$). The fact that an eigenspace is fixed is trivial. It is also easy to see that the sum of eigenspaces is always a direct sum, so $L$ is fixed by $\phi$.
A proof of the fact that $L^\perp$ is fixed by $\phi$ can be found here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_operator (properties in finite-dimensional case section).
What this means is that if we restrict $\phi_{|L^\perp}$, this will be an endomorphism from $L^\perp$ to $L^\perp$. So $\phi_{|L^\perp}$ will have some eigenvalue (since $\mathbb C$ is algebraically closed) and some eigenvector. All of this is assuming, of course, that $\dim L^\perp$ is at least $1$. Now all that is left is to see that if $v$ is an eigenvector of $\phi_{|L^\perp}$, then $v$ is also an eigenvector of $\phi$. This boils down to the fact that the orthogonal direct sum $V=L\oplus L^\perp$ is respected by $\phi=\phi_L\oplus \phi_{L^\perp}$. Therefore, $\phi(v)=\phi_{L^\perp}(v)$.
